# which URL is better for a search engine?

Tags: seo, url, optimization, google-website-optimizer

In 2 ways I can show The article URL in my website:
My Breadcrumbs website for a content to both of ways is this:

**home**>>**computer**>>**hardware**>>**cpu**>>this-is-an-article.html

**The First way:**
LINK of article : example.com/computer/hardware/cpu/this-is-an-article.html
catagory 1:       example.com/computer.html
catagory 2:       example.com/computer/hardware.html
catagory 3:       example.com/computer/hardware/cpu.html

**THe second way:**
LINK of article : example.com/cpu/this-is-an-article.html
catagory 1:       example.com/computer.html
catagory 2:       example.com/hardware.html
catagory 3:       example.com/cpu.html

**which one is the best for serach engine specialy google?**

Answer (score 0):

The first way is too many directories, too many keywords, I would not suggest except if you have millions of documents. It also enlarges urls by adding 10 - 20 characters and makes them less memorable.

The second is better. You can rank for a specific word, thats nice

Comment: tnx for answer. do you suggest me remove all categories? for example this URL:example.com/this-is-article.html is better the seond way?

Comment: Add one folder if you want to rank for that word. Do not use multiple categories, like /computer/hardware/cpu